# ¿Por qué una función queda fuera del scope al eliminar algo de firestore?

Tags: firebase, angular

Tengo el siguiente método que elimina una imagen del storage de Firebase (Eso lo hace sin problemas), pero dentro llamo al método `eliminarImagenDB` el cual no se ejecuta.

```
borrarImagen( nombre: string ) {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  let ruta = 'galeria-img';
  let ref = storageRef.child(`${ ruta }/${ nombre }`);
  //Delete the file
  ref.delete().then(function() {
    //File deleted successfully
    console.log(nombre, ' borrada exitosamente');
    this.eliminarImagenDB(ruta, nombre);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    console.error('Error ', error);
  });
}
```

Y justo debajo de esa función tengo `eliminarImagenDB()`

```
private eliminarImagenDB( ruta: string, nombre: string ) {
  console.log(ruta, ' ', nombre );
}
```

Pero la consola me muestra:

```
imagen.jpg  borrada exitosamente

Error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'eliminarImagenDB' of undefined
at eval (subir-imagen-galeria.service.ts:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a `this` que esta fuera de contexto en el callback

```
  // ...
  ref.delete().then(function() { // Declarando una función anónima
    //File deleted successfully
    console.log(nombre, ' borrada exitosamente');
    this.eliminarImagenDB(ruta, nombre);
  // ^ Aquí 'this' no es el mismo contexto global. 'this' pertenece a la función anónima.
  }).catch(function(error) {
  // ...
```

Una solución es usar [expresion de función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) que no tiene un contexto propio, toma el `this` de la clase en la que fue declarada.

```
  // ...
  ref.delete().then(() => { // Declarando una función flecha
    //File deleted successfully
    console.log(nombre, ' borrada exitosamente');
    this.eliminarImagenDB(ruta, nombre);
  // ^ Aquí 'this' apunta a contexto de donde fue declarada.
  }).catch(function(error) {
  // ...
```

Para más información podés referirte a [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this)